# Call JS function with attributes from another function

Tags: javascript

First of all i am not good enough in js.
I have two function in a page and i have to call another function in an existing function.
I have=>

```
function suggest1(inputString){
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions1').fadeOut();
    }
    else{
        $('#p_name').addClass('load');
        $.post("autosuggest.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data)
        {
            if(data.length >0) 
            {
                $('#suggestions1').fadeIn();
                $('#suggestionsList1').html(data);
                $('#p_name').removeClass('load');

            }
            });
        }

    }

    function fill1(thisValue) {
        $('#p_name').val(thisValue);
        $('#p_nameA').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions1').fadeOut();", 100);
    }
```

This is an auto suggest function
Ineed to call function which is bellow, which can use the value of $('#p_name').val(thisValue); in var name_tast. Is it possible or not?

```
function getAccaounce()
    {
        var name_tast = document.getElementById("p_nameA").value;

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax_accaounce.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'p_nameA': name_tast,
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#available1').html(data.message1);
                $('#price1').html(data.message2);
            }
       });
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes,you can do it. But shouldn't the `data` in your AJAX call be `'p_nameA': name_tast`

Comment: oh yes that's my mistake but how to and where to call getAccaounce()

Comment: It depends on from which point you need to make an `AJAX` call. It could be from any function in the same file or on two different files provided that both the files "see each other" meaning you have included both the `JS` files in your `HTML/TPL` file.

Comment: Personal information shouldn't be asked for or revealed on SO.

Comment: Just put `getAccaounce()` at the end of `suggest1` and check